# Эмуляция нажатия кнопки посредством WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь эмулировать нажатие кнопки на калькуляторе. Так как реальных кнопок класса Button в калькуляторе нет, и как подсказывали в предыдущих темах скорее всего кнопки нарисованные.
Смотрю через spy++ какие сообщения посылаются в окно калькулятора при нажатии к примеру на цифру 8:

```
000201C6  S  WM_PARENTNOTIFY fwEvent:WM_LBUTTONDOWN xPos:191 yPos:493
```

Посылаю такое же сообщение в окно Калькулятора:

```
HWND calculator_HWND = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Калькулятор");  //Получили HWND калькулятора

SendMessage(Parent_HWND, WM_PARENTNOTIFY, MAKEWPARAM(WM_LBUTTONDOWN,0), MAKELPARAM(191, 493));
```

Но в самом калькуляторе реакции никакой.
Точнее самое сообщение в окно приходит. После запуска кода, в spy++ видно, что приходит аналогичное сообщение, но сама цифра 8 - не нажимается.
На другом форуме подсказали, что калькулятор оскрее всего сделан на WinForms, а сами кнопки - это нарисованные кнопки, а не кнопки класса Button.
Как же тогда калькулятор обрабатывает нажатия кнопок, если не от оконных сообщений ? Только от событий мыши?

Comment: Может там сначала надо делать non-client события, потом move, а только потом down

Comment: user7860670, вне non-client - по идее я сделал вручную, то есть вручную навел курсор мыши на цифру 8 и после этого сработал код.

Comment: Похоже, что в UWP приложениях обработка ввода происходит как-то иначе: если клавиатурой нажимать, никаких сообщений не приходит вообще

Comment: обычно по нажатию кнопки мыши начинается анимация, а собственно «нажатие» происходит по отпусканию... второе событие в трейсере точно не приходит? а если всё же отправить его?

Comment: Fat-Zer, spy++ точно не фиксирует сообщение о fwEvent:WM_LBUTTONUP. Однако я побывал его отправлять сразу после WM_LBUTTONDOWN - ноль реакции.